# Making popup in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, popup

I am working on creating a pop-up in JSF for my project. The popup will be used for Country/State/City look-up.

The requirements are as follows:

1. It should be an overlay panel and not a new browser window

   > This is easier. I have multiple options
   >
   > 1. [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
   > 2. Some JSF library popup (ex. [richfaces dialog](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/modalPanel.jsf))
2. The pop-up should be a separate page (a different JSP/XHTML) so the pop-up code won't get copied in a lot of pages

   > This is also easy. I could make a separate JSP and use some include tag to include this jsp where ever the pop-up is required.
3. The pop-up JSP should be able to have form with controls that may result in post-back events within the pop-up. Like the popup may have search functionality. So there may be an in put textbox, a button along with a datatable on the pop-up. When the search button is clicked,
   some action needs to be executed to load the contents of the datatable, so the form (on the pop-up) will be submitted. This should not result in the pop-up being closed.

   > I am stuck up with this last requirement. If when the form (on pop-up) is submitted, the pop-up should not close, then this action should be asynchronous (AJAX). But the AJAX is not used in all the actions in my project. So If I need to solve this problem using AJAX, the AJAX script should be generic enough which won't require all the pop-up JSP's to re-write.
4. There might be a requirement to exchange data between the host page and the pop-up JSP.

   > May be this can be solved with some JS script. Am I correct ?

I need help with point# 3 and 4. In general if you are aware of any existing library to solve the problem, it would be great, but even if you could help with some directions, it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.x or JSF 2? Why don't you use a third party library like RichFaces or PrimeFaces that already has popup components? In case you can't use any of these, you can download their source code and copy/paste/adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0. The RichFaces and PrimeFaces dialog does not provide the functionality described at point# 3. We can't have complete form with search functionality.

Comment: These popups can do whatever you need, just use `<p:dialog> <h:form> ... </h:form> </p:dialog>`. Looks that you haven't tried or you have problems with it (and didn't come here to get an answer).

Comment: [Recommandation](http://gristmill.github.io/jquery-popbox/)

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı primefaces uses the same I believe

Comment: @kolossus I can delete the comment if you are sure about it?